# XML text field with predefined text including text breaks

Tags: xml, textfield

Let's say I have the following XML code:

```
<fields>
<field default="Open Questions:  Open Issues:  Summary:   " description="A short description about this item" id="description_test" name="Test-Description" required="true" type="text/html"/>

<field default="5" description="Some testnumber" id="testnumber" name="testnumber" required="true" type="integer"/>
</fields>
```

My issue is that I want to have a predefined text in the field which has the attribute type="text", however I want also to insert text breaks or paragraphs in the default field. Probably it would work with HTML-Tags since my Code is later shown on an HTML page, so I want to do somnething like:

```
default="Open Questions: " + <br /> + " Open Issues: " + <br /> + " Summary:   "
```

Any ideas how it could work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Carriage Return, Line Feed" in other words `\r\n` using their character entities where CR (Carriage Return) code is `&#13;` and LF (Line Feed) code is `&#10;`. Your code will become as follows :

```
<fields>
<field default="Open Questions: &#13;&#10; Open Issues: &#13;&#10; Summary:   " description="A short description about this item" id="description_test" name="Test-Description" required="true" type="text/html"/>

<field default="5" description="Some testnumber" id="testnumber" name="testnumber" required="true" type="integer"/>
</fields>
```

**EDIT**

You can also set the newline explicitly, see if this works for you :

```
  <fields>
    <field default="Open Questions: 
 Open Issues: 
 Summary:   " description="A short description about this item" id="description_test" name="Test-Description" required="true" type="text/html"/>

    <field default="5" description="Some testnumber" id="testnumber" name="testnumber" required="true" type="integer"/>
    </fields>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but alas it did not work for me. Could it be that the reason is that the programme I work with (Polarion ALM) shows the text-field as a Rich Text Field?

See here:
http://abload.de/img/xml_breaktzpxd.png

Comment: Check the edit and see if setting the newline explicitly takes effect in your DHTML editor, it seems the character entities are not being parsed by the editor, see if the new lines do get parsed and saved properly.